# Sending sqlcmd output file to directory that is a variable

Tags: batch-file, sqlcmd

Currently, the following code in a batch file works: it runs all SQL scripts in `%SCRIPTFOLDER%` and sends each script's output to a CSV within the same folder as the scripts.

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%S IN (
    'DIR /B "%SCRIPTFOLDER%\*.sql" '
) DO (
    sqlcmd -b -S %INSTANCE% -d %DATABASE% -i "%%~fS" -s "|" -o "%%~dpnS.csv" -W
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO errorhandling
    ECHO %%~nS.csv successfully created
)
```

What I'd like to do is allow the user to specify where the generated CSVs get sent to using a variable %OUTPUTFOLDER%.

I tried placing `%OUTPUTFOLDER%`, which is a full path, drive, and folders (e.g. D:\some folder\output) in various positions within `%%~dpnS.csv`. Specifically,

```
%%~dp%OUTPUTFOLDER%nS.csv
```

and

```
%%~dpn%OUTPUTFOLDER%S.csv
```

but they didn't work and I'm (probably obviously to you) woefully inept at batch file syntax!

I understand that `dp` is the drive and path and that `S` is the file name, but I'm not sure how to integrate that with a the variable that is the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iterating variable is %%S, the modifier `~dpn` forces an evaluation of drive path and name.

In this case you want to specify the drive and path yourself so depending on wether `%OUTPUTFOLDER%` has a trailing backslash

`-o "%OUTPUTFOLDER%%%~nS"`

or not use:

`-o "%OUTPUTFOLDER%\%%~nS"`

Comment: I was in the middle of answering my own question when you posted this. I did a LOT of trial and error, but finally came to the solution in your answer. The one with the slash added is what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: If in doubt add the `\ `in between, because double backslashes do not disturb, but a missing one does...